# Retrieve field groups from SharePoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to retrieve the existing field groups (from root) and display them in a dropdown list.

I'm using this code to retrieve all the columns (and display which group they're belonging to):

```
 var web = clientContext.Web;

                FieldCollection rootFields = web.Fields;

                clientContext.Load(
                    rootFields,
                     fields => fields
                      .Include(field => field.Group)
                   );
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (Field _fields in rootFields)
                {
                    fieldsList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = _fields.Group });
                }
```

This shows a few hundred groups (duplicates ofc), I want to narrow it down to just the few groups that exist, and sort out the duplicates. Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via Linq:

[Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) will sort the duplicates out of your result.

```
var results = rootFields.ToList().Select(field => field.Group).Distinct();

foreach (var_group in results)
{
    fieldsList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = _group });
}
```

Comment: foreach cannot convert string to class ...Field. If i use var instead of field in the foreach I cannot receive the .Group definition.

Comment: @RangeRover see my edit, the results only are a collection of string's which are representing the group names